# Replacing Address of entry point windows works only under a debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, assembly, packer

I am trying to understand how the PE works under windows and so am going down the route of writing a packer.
So I took the address of entry point, that points to _mainCRTStartup and replaced it with a value that points to a "jmp _mainCRTStartup". 
When I run it under a debugger my program runs fine but if I just launch the executable without a debugger it crashes and I am unable to attach a debugger post crash, the debugger says that it failed to attach to the crashing process.

I guess my questions would be: Should my approach work? If so what can I try to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Max

Comment: OEP? You mean the AddressOfEntryPoint field?

Comment: That's right, I think OEP stands for Origin Entry Point.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the a value relative to the actual load address of the executable (normally the value ImageBase).  So if the actual entry point in memory is supposed to be 0x401570 and ImageBase is 0x400000 then the value should be 0x1570.

Comment: Yes it's using a correct relative address, what I fail to understand is why does it work under a debugger but not without one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out everything worked fine, I forgot to handle an exception in an anti-debug routine that would crash the exe if it wasn't ran in a debugger.